# View Schedule on Calendar

Tags: java, mysql, swing, calendar

I'm working on an application that has the user open a calendar view, and schedule different tasks (similar to what you can do in outlook). I have the Calendar view, but don't know where to go from here. This is borrowed code btw. I've updated some of it to meet some of my intent.

I'm thinking of using mysql as the database to store the task dates, but how do I populate my calendar with the dates from the database? I've attached the borrowed code. Any suggestions are welcome...

```
//Import packages
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ViewCalendar {

     JLabel lblMonth, lblYear;
     JButton btnPrev, btnNext;
     JTable tblCalendar;
     JComboBox cmbYear;
     JFrame frmMain;
     Container pane;
     DefaultTableModel mtblCalendar; //Table model
     JScrollPane stblCalendar; //The scrollpane
     JPanel pnlCalendar;
     int realYear, realMonth, realDay, currentYear, currentMonth;

    public void viewCalendar() {
        System.out.println("*Calendar open*");
        //Look and feel
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        }

        //Prepare frame
        frmMain = new JFrame("Scheduled Repairs"); //Create frame
        frmMain.setSize(330, 375); //Set size to 400x400 pixels
        pane = frmMain.getContentPane(); //Get content pane
        pane.setLayout(null); //Apply null layout
        frmMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Close when X is clicked

        //Create controls
        lblMonth = new JLabel("January");
        lblYear = new JLabel("Change year:");
        cmbYear = new JComboBox();
        btnPrev = new JButton("<<");
        btnNext = new JButton(">>");
        mtblCalendar = new DefaultTableModel() {

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int mColIndex) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        tblCalendar = new JTable(mtblCalendar);
        stblCalendar = new JScrollPane(tblCalendar);
        pnlCalendar = new JPanel(null);

        //Set border
        pnlCalendar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Calendar"));

        //Register action listeners
        btnPrev.addActionListener(new btnPrev_Action());
        btnNext.addActionListener(new btnNext_Action());
        cmbYear.addActionListener(new cmbYear_Action());

        //Add controls to pane
        pane.add(pnlCalendar);
        pnlCalendar.add(lblMonth);
        pnlCalendar.add(lblYear);
        pnlCalendar.add(cmbYear);
        pnlCalendar.add(btnPrev);
        pnlCalendar.add(btnNext);
        pnlCalendar.add(stblCalendar);

        //Set bounds
        pnlCalendar.setBounds(0, 0, 320, 335);
        lblMonth.setBounds(160 - lblMonth.getPreferredSize().width / 2, 25, 100, 25);
        lblYear.setBounds(10, 305, 80, 20);
        cmbYear.setBounds(230, 305, 80, 20);
        btnPrev.setBounds(10, 25, 50, 25);
        btnNext.setBounds(260, 25, 50, 25);
        stblCalendar.setBounds(10, 50, 300, 250);

        //Make frame visible
        frmMain.setResizable(true);
        frmMain.setVisible(true);

        //Get real month/year
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); //Create calendar
        realDay = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); //Get day
        realMonth = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH); //Get month
        realYear = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR); //Get year
        currentMonth = realMonth; //Match month and year
        currentYear = realYear;

        //Add headers
        String[] headers = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"}; //All headers
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            mtblCalendar.addColumn(headers[i]);
        }

        tblCalendar.getParent().setBackground(tblCalendar.getBackground()); //Set background

        //No resize/reorder
        tblCalendar.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
        tblCalendar.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

        //Single cell selection
        tblCalendar.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        tblCalendar.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        tblCalendar.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        //Set row/column count
        tblCalendar.setRowHeight(38);
        mtblCalendar.setColumnCount(7);
        mtblCalendar.setRowCount(6);

        //Populate table
        for (int i = realYear - 100; i <= realYear + 100; i++) {
            cmbYear.addItem(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        //Refresh calendar
        refreshCalendar(realMonth, realYear); //Refresh calendar
    }

    public  void refreshCalendar(int month, int year) {
        //Variables
        String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
        int nod, som; //Number Of Days, Start Of Month

        //Allow/disallow buttons
        btnPrev.setEnabled(true);
        btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        if (month == 0 && year <= realYear - 10) {
            btnPrev.setEnabled(false);
        } //Too early
        if (month == 11 && year >= realYear + 100) {
            btnNext.setEnabled(false);
        } //Too late
        lblMonth.setText(months[month]); //Refresh the month label (at the top)
        lblMonth.setBounds(160 - lblMonth.getPreferredSize().width / 2, 25, 180, 25); //Re-align label with calendar
        cmbYear.setSelectedItem(String.valueOf(year)); //Select the correct year in the combo box

        //Clear table
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                mtblCalendar.setValueAt(null, i, j);
            }
        }

        //Get first day of month and number of days
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
        nod = cal.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        som = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        //Draw calendar
        for (int i = 1; i <= nod; i++) {
            int row = new Integer((i + som - 2) / 7);
            int column = (i + som - 2) % 7;
            mtblCalendar.setValueAt(i, row, column);
        }

        //Apply renderers
        tblCalendar.setDefaultRenderer(tblCalendar.getColumnClass(0), new tblCalendarRenderer());
    }

     class tblCalendarRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, selected, focused, row, column);
            if (column == 0 || column == 6) { //Week-end
                setBackground(new Color(255, 220, 220));
            } else { //Week
                setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            }
            if (value != null) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(value.toString()) == realDay && currentMonth == realMonth && currentYear == realYear) { //Today
                    setBackground(new Color(220, 220, 255));
                }
            }
            setBorder(null);
            setForeground(Color.black);
            return this;
        }
    }

     class btnPrev_Action implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (currentMonth == 0) { //Back one year
                currentMonth = 11;
                currentYear -= 1;
            } else { //Back one month
                currentMonth -= 1;
            }
            refreshCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
        }
    }

     class btnNext_Action implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (currentMonth == 11) { //Foward one year
                currentMonth = 0;
                currentYear += 1;
            } else { //Foward one month
                currentMonth += 1;
            }
            refreshCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
        }
    }

     class cmbYear_Action implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (cmbYear.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                String b = cmbYear.getSelectedItem().toString();
                currentYear = Integer.parseInt(b);
                refreshCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
            }
        }
    }
}
```